# find the distribution to number of vehicles crossing an intersection

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I have a data for of vehicles crossing an intersection in a particular time of day for example (7:00-7:30) for a year. I want to find the best distribution which fits the data.

I guess I should think of discrete distributions such as Poisson, binomial, ..... Am I correct or I should use different approach?

Comment: Probably best to fit a poisson model as we're dealing with time.

Comment: @Remy thank you. I tried poisson and binomial but the goodness of fit test showed the null hypothesis of that the data follows poisson or binomial is rejected. Do you suggest any other distributions?

Comment: There is no reason any particular distribution with a 'name' would have to fit your data. // If numbers of vehicles is large, then a continuous distribution family might work: normal, exponential, gamma, etc. // Minitab has a distribution ID procedure and there is a library in R for the same purpose.

Comment: It depends on the data. Nothing can be said in general.